# Any statistics available regarding relative popularity of OpenId providers?

Tags: authentication, openid, openid-provider

I'm using OpenId, and am providing buttons for all the usual suspects, but I'd like to be a little more scientific about it.

**Are there any public stats regarding numbers of users for each provider?**

Comment: UpTheCreek, which API are you using?  Are you using a guide?  Which one?  I'm looking to implement this on one of my sites shortly...

Comment: @webnet: I'm using DotNetOpenAuth. I pieced together info from different sources on the web - what platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you "providing buttons for all the usual suspects" ?!

One of the main reasons for OpenID is to **avoid** the NASCAR problem (which requires buttons for all the usual suspects).

**One** OpenID button should be enough.

Comment: Heh, that's lovely in theory - but this is not realistic. Show me one successful site that does this.

Comment: Yeah ok, but you've still got the OpenId, Facebook, Twitter options there (which aren't open id - but how many normal users realise that?).  In any case, this 'answer' would be better suited as a comment, as it does not attempt to answer the question asked.

Comment: Also, take a look at the login UI examples gallery on the official OpenId site - it seems they endorse multiple buttons: http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/25453698/Gallery

Comment: The question was about providing buttons "for all the usual [OpenID]-suspects". My answer essentially is: please do not do that. I do not object to additional buttons for non-OpenID accounts.